# Abnormal voltage drop across n-mosfet in multisim

Tags: mosfet, simulation, spice, multisim

been playing around with multisim, and i've added in a custom fet from infineon as an example and i noticed something a tad off.

[image: bigVds voltage]
when the Vds in my sim is higher than 12.5, it seems like the voltage drop across the device kinda goes wacky where it sits at 10.6.

correct me if im wrong but i would of expected something drastically less with a RdsMax of 1.5mOlms

im i correct to assume that these a range these components are valid to?
and if so is that standard practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 16 ohm resistor in series with the source and as soon as the MOSFET starts conducting that resistor develops a volt drop that degrades the effective voltage applied between gate and source and leads to a situation where the MOSFET operates no longer as a switch but linearly. It's called source degradation.

> *correct me if im wrong but i would of expected something drastically
> less with a RdsMax of 1.5mOlms*

The MOSFET's on resistance is no longer relevant with a circuit that produces source degradation. If you want to switch the full 50 volt supply across the 16 ohm resistor, the you need to connect the source to 0 volts and put the load in series with the drain.

Comment: oh ok, appreciate the tip. i wasnt aware of the term source degradation.